# SonarQube 6.2 - Change default landing page to /projects from /about

Tags: sonarqube

The SonarQube 6.2 product has dramatically changed its skin. I am still playing with it, and my first impression is that I like it, but one thing that is bugging me and will surely confuse my users is the default landing page for my host (e.g. http://sonar.example.com ) is redirected to http://sonar.example.com/about instead of http://sonar.example.com/projects which is a pretty swift departure from where we used to be previously. I think it would be more useful to go to /projects by default. How can I get this as the default landing page instead of /about?

I haven't found any likely sonar.conf variable, nor anything in the Administration panels... Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able/permitted to modify the files in 
`installdir\web\WEB-INF\app\controllers`

you could change the file `landing_controller.rb`

```
def index
    if logged_in?
      return redirect_to :controller => 'projects', :action => 'favorite'
    else
      return redirect_to :controller => 'projects'  //here was 'about'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the default landing page via configuration. Please note that the default landing page has changed only for non authenticated user. You can:

- authenticate. The next time you come back the default landing page will be the Projects page
- save the projects page as a browser favorite

Answer (score 0):

I am working with sonarqube 6.4, seems it is impossible to change this behavior as I found the web contents from install dir was refactored by reactJS and minimized.

I would like to suggest you checkout official docs about [Look and Feel Settings](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Look+and+Feel), you are able to add custom text(html supported) on about page, what I had done is adding a redirect link with info to help users go to projects page.

[Update Look and Feel - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EOSG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tested in 6.7 LTS:
You need a tool to search over files, like Notepad++

Search within the `"installdir\web\WEB-INF\"` Folder in every *.js for the String
`+"/about"`  (including the quotation marks)

You should find a passage like this:

```
window.location.pathname!==window.baseUrl+"/about"
```

Change it to:

```
window.location.pathname!==window.baseUrl+"/projects"
```

//EDIT

The js-files are minimized but the variables for window.location.pathname are build in variables, so they must not be changed by a minimizer. 
Therfore the text passage mentioned above, is in there, even if it is hard to find.